# Google Translate adds spaces around special characters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

If I enter `**Dit is mijn vraag**` into Google Translate, whether it's through the API or on the web view, it will translate it into `** This is my question **`. It adds spaces around the `**` which messes up the Markdown parser we run it through later...

Has anyone else encountered this, and if so, found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have replicated your case, with different target languages and different special characters symbols. In all cases, I indeed get similar behavior as yours. I haven't found any information that could explain the reason of this to happen, but there is an active [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119256504) with similar behavior.

This happens for `html` and `text` format API calls. You can follow the link for more information. As a workaround for now, if you are using the API call, after you get the response, process it by finding all `**[SPACE]`, `[SPACE]**` char sequences and replacing them with `**`.